# return address of memory allocated in function

Tags: c, memory, function

When memory is allocated in a function, isn't it impossible to use that memory outside the function by returning its address?

Are there exceptions? It seems the following is such an "example":

```
const char * f() {  
  return "HELLO";  
}
```

How to explain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it's impossible?  It sounds like you're confusing it with the rule about not returning addresses to *local* variables to calling functions.  You can't do that because variables local to a function have a lifetime only for the duration of that function call; once the function returns, those variables become garbage.

There are things that have lifetimes that extend beyond the lifetime of the function call; it's okay to return addresses to them.  Examples of these things are blocks of memory allocated on the heap (e.g. with `malloc`) or are things that have static storage duration (e.g. global variables and string literals).

Answer (score 3):

String literals are allocated statically, so returning the address of a string literal like "HELLO" is safe, and it can be used outside the function without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

"Hello" is a constant. It does not disappear so it is OK to use the pointer. A local variable is another story...